# can we use printf statement inside printf() function in C language

Tags: c, printf

is the following statement correct in C?

```
printf(" the string is %s", printf("xyz"));
```

I mean, is it possible to use 1 `printf` statement inside `printf` function?
if possible then please send the proper syntax for that expression.

Comment: Hint: What does _printf_ return?

Comment: why the downvote? this is a perfectly reasonable question to ask for someone not familiar with C.

Comment: because he could have that figured out just by reading the manual

Comment: I'd like to know why you think you need this. What are you trying to do? This will compile since printf returns a value, but the format is wrong (should be %d), and the second printf will be executed before the first (because it is a parameter to the first printf).

Comment: @PeterMiehle maybe the OP doesn't really understand return values, call parameters, and format strings. I think questioning the motive so answers can propose a better approach would be more appropriate than downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed, so the above statement would be wrong as your formatstring tries to print a string.

You could do it like this though:

```
printf("characters printed: %d", printf("xyz"));
```

If you want to output the result of a formatted string, you would have to use `snprintf` first, printing it to an array, which in turn you can use to print as a string then.

Example:

```
 char s[100];
 snprint(s, sizeof(s), "My string %d", 3);
 printf(" the string is %s", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not correct but, you can use printf within printf.
Upon successful return, `printf` functions return the number of characters printed (not  including  the  trailing  '\0'  used  to  end  output  to strings).

you can use like:

```
printf(" the string is %d", printf("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What printf does is just push characters to the buffered output stream.  print returns:

On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned.

If a multibyte character encoding error occurs while writing wide characters, errno is set to EILSEQ and a negative number is returned.

so if you are looking to print any of those out, you can with that second printf.  But it does not return a string, those characters are in the buffered output stream until one of these happen: program's termination, a '\n' is encountered, buffer is full, or a command like ffslush() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax :-

```
printf ("Your String Length :: %d",printf("TestString"));
```

1) First it will execute inner printf

2) inner printf return with the string length.

3) that is used in outer printf with %d specifier.

Answer (score 0):

**It's pretty simple.** 
First `printf()` represent the main value, then rest of `printf()` count the number of print value.
**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i = 43;
     printf("%d", printf("%d", printf("%d", printf("%d", i))));
     getch();
}
```